# Calling a function in a while True loop

Tags: python, while-loop

**Background** - I have a `.py` script that makes a `GET` call to an API, saves the response as a `.json` file, before saving and returning the `api_response` as a variable, for use in the `def unpack_response` function, which performs various actions to the API returned data

**Issue** - As the API is unreliable and frequently times out, I have added `while True:` statement to `def unpack_response():`, with the intention of looping a segment of code. Importantly, the first line in this function, calls a function that calls the API(`api_response = response_writer()`) which offers the `api_response`. Since implementing the `while True:` statement, my code tanks and throws up the following error -

**Error returning** (since implementing `while True`):

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
UnboundLocalError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-8-a3f8a13befee> in <module>
     36     print("---------------------------\n","EXCEPTION REPORT:", excep_row_count, "rows", "\n---------------------------")
     37 
---> 38 xlsx_writer()

<ipython-input-8-a3f8a13befee> in xlsx_writer()
      1 # Function that writes Exceptions Report and API Response as a consolidated .xlsx file.
      2 def xlsx_writer():
----> 3     df_raw, exceptions_df = ownership_qc()
      4 
      5 #   Creating and defining filename for exceptions report

<ipython-input-7-3c1d5b73cc07> in ownership_qc()
      3 
      4 #   Setting QC Columns
----> 5     df = unpack_response()
      6 
      7 #   Making a copy of df (normalized API response) to be written by def_xlsx_writer() function to same .xslsx as exceptions_df

<ipython-input-6-8c186a2a5f7a> in unpack_response()
     15 
     16 #   Holding Account refered to as 'name' in JSON file, and not found in column list. Therefore requires manual renaming.
---> 17     df.rename(columns={'name': 'Holding Account'}, inplace=True)
     18 
     19 #   Reordering columns, to match View in Addepar

UnboundLocalError: local variable 'df' referenced before assignment
```

**Function before `while True:` statement implemented:** (this works perfectly) -

```
def unpack_response():  
    api_response = response_writer()
    df = pd.json_normalize(api_response['data']['attributes']['total']['children'])
    df.drop(columns=['grouping', 'entity_id'], inplace=True)
    df.columns = df.columns.str.replace(r'columns.', '')
    column_name_mapper = {column['key']: column['display_name'] for column in api_response['meta']['columns']}
    df.rename(columns=column_name_mapper, inplace=True)

    df.rename(columns={'name': 'Holding Account'}, inplace=True)

    column_names = ["Holding Account", "Entity ID", "Holding Account Number", "Adjusted Value (USD)", "% Ownership", "Model Type", "Valuation (USD)", "JP Custodian",
                   "Top Level Owner", "Top Level Legal Entity", "Direct Owner", "Online Status", "Financial Service", "Placeholder or Fee Basis", 
                    "Account Close Date", "Ownership Audit Note"]
    df = df.reindex(columns=column_names)

    index = df.index
    number_of_rows = len(index)
    print("---------------------------------------------\n",
          "DATAFRAME CONSTRUCTED SUCCESSFULLY:", number_of_rows, "rows", "\n---------------------------------------------")
    
    return df
```

**Function after `while True:` statement implemented:** (returns the above error) -

```
def unpack_response():
    while True:
        try:    
            api_response = response_writer()
            df = pd.json_normalize(api_response['data']['attributes']['total']['children'])
            df.drop(columns=['grouping', 'entity_id'], inplace=True)
            df.columns = df.columns.str.replace(r'columns.', '')
            column_name_mapper = {column['key']: column['display_name'] for column in api_response['meta']['columns']}
            df.rename(columns=column_name_mapper, inplace=True)
        except KeyError:
                    print("-----------------------------------\n","API TIMEOUT ERROR: TRYING AGAIN...", "\n-----------------------------------\n")
        break

    df.rename(columns={'name': 'Holding Account'}, inplace=True)

    column_names = ["Holding Account", "Entity ID", "Holding Account Number", "Adjusted Value (USD)", "% Ownership", "Model Type", "Valuation (USD)", "JP Custodian",
                   "Top Level Owner", "Top Level Legal Entity", "Direct Owner", "Online Status", "Financial Service", "Placeholder or Fee Basis", 
                    "Account Close Date", "Ownership Audit Note"]
    df = df.reindex(columns=column_names)

    index = df.index
    number_of_rows = len(index)
    print("---------------------------------------------\n",
          "DATAFRAME CONSTRUCTED SUCCESSFULLY:", number_of_rows, "rows", "\n---------------------------------------------")
    
    return df
```

**Question** - this is my first time implementing a `while True` statement and I wondered if I have done this incorrectly? And if anyone can help identify and teach me how to correctly implement

Comment: I assume you want it to RETRY if it fails, and EXIT the loop if it succeeds.  If so, then you need to move the `break` to before the `except`.  As it is, you will always exit the loop first time through, even if you get an exception before creating the `df` variable, which is why you got the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You break the while true loop in the end, no matter if an exception is thrown or not by using "break". Then the code crashes at the following line because "df" is not declared:

```
df.rename(columns={'name': 'Holding Account'}, inplace=True)
```

If you change the break of the while true loop accordingly, it should keep on going until it succeeds:

```
def unpack_response():
while True:
    try:    
        api_response = response_writer()
        df = pd.json_normalize(api_response['data']['attributes']['total']['children'])
        df.drop(columns=['grouping', 'entity_id'], inplace=True)
        df.columns = df.columns.str.replace(r'columns.', '')
        column_name_mapper = {column['key']: column['display_name'] for column in api_response['meta']['columns']}
        df.rename(columns=column_name_mapper, inplace=True)
        break
    except KeyError:
        print("-----------------------------------\n","API TIMEOUT ERROR: TRYING AGAIN...", "\n-----------------------------------\n")
    
df.rename(columns={'name': 'Holding Account'}, inplace=True)

column_names = ["Holding Account", "Entity ID", "Holding Account Number", "Adjusted Value (USD)", "% Ownership", "Model Type", "Valuation (USD)", "JP Custodian",
               "Top Level Owner", "Top Level Legal Entity", "Direct Owner", "Online Status", "Financial Service", "Placeholder or Fee Basis", 
                "Account Close Date", "Ownership Audit Note"]
df = df.reindex(columns=column_names)

index = df.index
number_of_rows = len(index)
print("---------------------------------------------\n",
      "DATAFRAME CONSTRUCTED SUCCESSFULLY:", number_of_rows, "rows", "\n---------------------------------------------")

return df
```

You should really consider to add a time.sleep(10) so you retry with a delay.